# Access aws dynamodb using boto3 when MFA has been set. Getting ClientError

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Previously when I did not set MFA to login to AWS console I've connected to dynamodb by

```
dynamo = boto3.resource('dynamodb',
                        region_name='ap-northeast-2',
                        endpoint_url='http://dynamodb.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com')
table = dynamo.Table('tablename')
```

and querying to that table was perfectly fine.

```
response = table.query(
    KeyConditionExpression =Key("user_id").eq(123123)
)
```

After I've set MFA for additional security to login to AWS console and now when I execute above code I get:

```
ClientError: An error occurred (UnrecognizedClientException) when calling the Query operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.
```

I use tunnel for RDB, is there something like that I could use for connecting to dynamodb or is there a permission I need in order to access dynamodb?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you enable MFA, SDK **does not automatically** know how to work with it. Your regular IAM user's API and SECRET keys are no longer enough. Instead you need to use temporary credentials created only for your MFA session.

To make MFA work with boto3 you have to explicitly call [get_session_token](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sts.html#STS.Client.get_session_token):

> MFA-enabled IAM users would **need to call GetSessionToken** and submit an MFA code that is associated with their MFA device. Using the **temporary security credentials** that are returned from the call, IAM users can then make programmatic calls to API operations that require MFA authentication.

Using `get_session_token` you can call `sts` service which is going to provide you with temporary credentials based on your MFA details:

```
sts = boto3.client('sts')

mfa_response = sts.get_session_token(
    DurationSeconds=123,
    SerialNumber='string',
    TokenCode='string'
)
```

The call will return the credentials in `mfa_response` which you can use to **create a new boto3 session**. For example:

```
mfa_session = boto3.session.Session(
      aws_access_key_id=mfa_session['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'], 
      aws_secret_access_key=mfa_session['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey'], 
      aws_session_token=mfa_session['Credentials']['SessionToken'])

dynamo = mfa_session.resource('dynamodb', ...)

# and the rest of the code
```

Comment: what is SerialNumber? I keep getting `ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Invalid range for parameter DurationSeconds, value: 3, valid range: 900-inf
Invalid length for parameter SerialNumber, value: 6, valid range: 9-inf` Can be fixed by replace 123 with 900 and 'string' with stringgggg but when I insert mfa code in TokenCode It keeps on giving me `ClientError`

Comment: @Ambleu Example of serial number is shown [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/authenticate-mfa-cli/)

Comment: I've went into console, copy pasted assigned MFA device name that goes like `arn:aws:iam.......` I've entered TokenCode as what my phone MFA gives me. It still gives ClientError. I referred to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/get-session-token.html for information about each parameter

Comment: @Ambleu Can you try doing this in aws CLI. Not boto3 for now. Would be good to try most basic approach to ensure that the MFA works as intended, before trying to use it in boto3.